# LNK2022 metadata operation failed CLI

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, vector, .net-4.0

Написал код, попробовал скомпилировать, получил это:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131188) : Несовместимые объявления полей в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_impl<cliext::vector<double> ^,0>; поля: _Myarray): (0x04000010).  Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131188) : Несовместимые объявления полей в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_impl<cliext::vector<double> ^,0>; поля: _Mysize): (0x04000011).   Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131188) : Несовместимые объявления полей в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_impl<cliext::vector<double> ^,0>; поля: _Mygen): (0x04000012).    Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Разное количество полей в повторяющихся типах (cliext.impl.vector_impl<cliext::vector<double> ^,0>): (0x0200001e).   Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131188) : Несовместимые объявления полей в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_impl<bool,0>; поля: _Myarray): (0x0400001a).  Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131188) : Несовместимые объявления полей в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_impl<bool,0>; поля: _Mysize): (0x0400001b).   Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131188) : Несовместимые объявления полей в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_impl<bool,0>; поля: _Mygen): (0x0400001c).    Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (801311D7) : Разное количество полей в повторяющихся типах (cliext.impl.vector_impl<bool,0>): (0x0200002a).   Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118B) : Несовместимые реализованные интерфейсы в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_impl<cliext::vector<double> ^,0>; интерфейсы: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall): (0x09000001). Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118B) : Несовместимые реализованные интерфейсы в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_impl<cliext::vector<double> ^,0>; интерфейсы: System.IDisposable): (0x09000002).  Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118B) : Несовместимые реализованные интерфейсы в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_base<cliext::vector<double> ^,0>; интерфейсы: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvFastcall): (0x09000003).    Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118B) : Несовместимые реализованные интерфейсы в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_base<cliext::vector<double> ^,0>; интерфейсы: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile): (0x09000004).  Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118B) : Несовместимые реализованные интерфейсы в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_base<cliext::vector<double> ^,0>; интерфейсы: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.SuppressMergeCheckAttribute): (0x09000005). Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118B) : Несовместимые реализованные интерфейсы в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_impl<bool,0>; интерфейсы: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsConst): (0x0900000b). Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118B) : Несовместимые реализованные интерфейсы в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_impl<bool,0>; интерфейсы: System.IDisposable): (0x0900000c).  Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118B) : Несовместимые реализованные интерфейсы в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_base<bool,0>; интерфейсы: System.IDisposable): (0x0900000d).  Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118B) : Несовместимые реализованные интерфейсы в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_base<bool,0>; интерфейсы: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong): (0x0900000e).  Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118B) : Несовместимые реализованные интерфейсы в повторяющихся типах (типы: cliext.impl.vector_base<bool,0>; интерфейсы: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute): (0x0900000f).   Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Несовместимые сведения о макетах в повторяющихся типах (cliext._Dehandle<cliext::vector<double> ^>): (0x0200001c).   Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Несовместимые сведения о макетах в повторяющихся типах (cliext.is_handle<cliext::vector<double> ^>): (0x0200001d).   Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Несовместимые сведения о макетах в повторяющихся типах (cliext._Dehandle<bool>): (0x02000028).   Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Несовместимые сведения о макетах в повторяющихся типах (cliext.is_handle<bool>): (0x02000029).   Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131195) : Несовместимые особые атрибуты. (0x0c000016). Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131195) : Несовместимые особые атрибуты. (0x0c000018). Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131195) : Несовместимые особые атрибуты. (0x0c00001a). Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131195) : Несовместимые особые атрибуты. (0x0c000029). Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131195) : Несовместимые особые атрибуты. (0x0c00002c). Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131195) : Несовместимые особые атрибуты. (0x0c00002e). Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\TestsTimeTree.obj 1   
Error   LNK1255 link failed because of metadata errors  Coursework  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Coursework\Coursework\LINK  1
```

Что может быть не так?
Код класса:

```
//testTimeVector.h
#ifndef _TESTSTIMETREE
#define _TESTSTIMETREE
 
 
#include <cliext\vector>
 
#include "LinearEquationsSystem.h"
 
ref class TestsTimeTree
{
public:
    TestsTimeTree();
    System::Void PushTime(System::UInt32 size, System::Double time);
    cliext::vector<System::Double> ^ GetLSMTimesVector();
private:
    System::Void CheckLSMVector(System::Void);
    System::Void CalcLSM(System::UInt32 index);
    System::Void CalcCoefficients(System::UInt32 index);
 
    cliext::vector<cliext::vector<System::Double>^> ^ testTimeVector;
    cliext::vector<System::Double> ^ leastSquareMethodTimesVector;
    cliext::vector<System::Boolean> ^ isTimeChanged;
 
    System::UInt32 numOfTests;
 
    System::UInt64 summOfX;
    System::UInt64 summOfPowX;
 
    System::Double summOfY;
    System::Double summOfYX;
 
    System::Double a0;
    System::Double a1;
 
};
 
#endif // !_TESTSTIMETREE
```

Cpp:

```
//TestsTimeTree.cpp
#include "TestsTimeTree.h"
 
 
 
TestsTimeTree::TestsTimeTree()
{
    testTimeVector               = gcnew cliext::vector<cliext::vector<System::Double> ^>();
    leastSquareMethodTimesVector = gcnew cliext::vector<System::Double>();
    isTimeChanged                = gcnew cliext::vector<System::Boolean>();
 
    numOfTests = 0u;
 
    summOfX    = 0.0;
    summOfPowX = 0.0;
    summOfY    = 0.0;
    summOfYX   = 0.0;
}
 
System::Void TestsTimeTree::PushTime(System::UInt32 size, System::Double time)
{
    // If current expected size of task is smaller then the task size
    // than resize expected size of task
    size++;
    if (testTimeVector->size() < size) {
        System::Int32 oldSize = testTimeVector->size();
        testTimeVector->resize(size);
        leastSquareMethodTimesVector->resize(size);
        isTimeChanged->resize(size);
        for (size_t i = oldSize; i < size; i++) {
            testTimeVector[i] = gcnew cliext::vector<System::Double>();
            isTimeChanged[i] = false;
            leastSquareMethodTimesVector[i] = 0.0;
        }
    }
    size--;
 
    // Push our time
    testTimeVector[size]->push_back(time);
    isTimeChanged[size] = true;
    numOfTests++;
 
    CalcCoefficients(size);
 
    //----
    CheckLSMVector();
 
    CalcLSM(size);
 
    return System::Void();
}
 
cliext::vector<System::Double>^ TestsTimeTree::GetLSMTimesVector()
{
    return gcnew cliext::vector<System::Double>(leastSquareMethodTimesVector);
}
 
System::Void TestsTimeTree::CheckLSMVector(System::Void)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < testTimeVector->size(); i++) {
        if (isTimeChanged[i]) {
            CalcLSM(i);
        }
    }
    return System::Void();
}
 
System::Void TestsTimeTree::CalcLSM(System::UInt32 index)
{
    System::Double result = System::Double::MaxValue;
    System::Int32 minIdx = 0;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < testTimeVector[index]->size(); i++) {
        if (System::Math::Pow(testTimeVector[index]->at(i) - a0 - a1 * index, 2.0) <
            System::Math::Pow(testTimeVector[index]->at(minIdx) - a0 - a1 * index, 2.0)) {
            minIdx = i;
        }
    }
    leastSquareMethodTimesVector[index] = testTimeVector[index]->at(minIdx);
    return System::Void();
}
 
System::Void TestsTimeTree::CalcCoefficients(System::UInt32 index)
{
    summOfX += index;
    System::Double y = testTimeVector[index]->at(testTimeVector[index]->size() - 1);
    summOfY += y;
    summOfPowX += System::Math::Pow(index, 2.0);
    summOfYX += y*index;
    
    array<System::Double, 2> ^ inputMatrix = gcnew array<System::Double, 2>(2, 3){{numOfTests, summOfX,    summOfY },
                                                                                  {summOfX,    summOfPowX, summOfYX}};
    LinearEquationsSystem linearEquationSystem(inputMatrix, 2);
 
    cliext::vector<System::Double> ^ resultCoefficients = linearEquationSystem.Calculate(0.0000001);
 
    a0 = resultCoefficients[0];
    a1 = resultCoefficients[1];
 
    return System::Void();
}
```